# how prevent angular compile specify element

Tags: angularjs

I'm developing a chrome extension using angularjs (with a content script open a popup),but it meet some problem when it's parent page already use angularjs, it's parent try to compile the content inserted, so  is there anyway to prevent the parent angularjs instance to compile the element I added, and the angularjs instance in extension can bootstrap the element manually ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to answer without an example, or what is your extension flow.

Basically, angular shouldn't compile anything on it's own, it either does it when bootstrapping the app, or when you explicitly tell it to.

What I guess you are doing is have the html change before angular is loaded, and then when it loads it compiles your stuff as well.
Try adding your directives etc. *after* angular has finished loading on the main page (how to detect that angular finished bootstrapping is a whole other question :)).

And after you add your new element with your ng-app `<div ng-app="myAngularExtensionApp"></div>`, however I am not sure how it will work if it's nested inside another angular application, I don't think it will allow you to do it. If the ng-app of the main application is on the body you can add your div outside the body (weird, but legit), and it shouldn't conflict. but if it's on the html it might cause problems. (I tested it, you can bootstrap another one inside an existing app, but it can cause some really weird problems, I'd avoid it).

A bullet proof solution, that makes things a little more complicated is one I used and I like it alot:

Create an iframe on the page, which you add the angularJS script inside, and it will be your application, do not set the src of the iframe, but rather use iframe.document.open() .write(
`<html><body ng-app="myExtensionApp">` etc (i.e. a complete bone structure of an angular page), now since the src is the same, you won't have same origin problems, and you can access the main page with top.

I recommend having services that will interact with the main page.

I am not sure what you want to do, but if you want a directive on the main page for example, first create it in the iframe, then move it to the main page via jquery, it will belong to YOUR angular application (since scope binding is based on prototype and the chain doesn't get broken by moving the element), it will keep reacting to changes to your scope.

However you have to remember that styles are unaffected etc.

Comment: thks for patient, may be I haven't make clear with my problem. my chrome extension working on the other page (not my web page), when the main page is a angular page as  <html ng-app>...</html> , and my extension will insert some content as <div id='et'> ... <div> into the document , I bootstrap this element manually, but the angular instance of main page will also try to parse the element which I added . I think that will be a problem.  by the way , use iframe is good for decouple the style, but is hard to communicate with the main page (different domain)

Comment: It's not a different domain if you do the method I told you. When you only add an iframe, and not set the src but write directly to the iframe the same origin policy stays intact.